# Can non IP data formats over cat5 / 6 (eg. RS232 etc..) damage an IP switch?

Tags: ethernet, power, serial, rs232

Can various data formats can be run over a cat5 / 6 cable with RJ45 ends.

These can include (not an exhaustive list)

- HDbaseT
- RS232 / RS485 (using an RJ45 to serial adaptor on the end)
- POE Cat6 (not a data format, but also not a "vanilla" data connection)

If these non IP formats are inputted into a standard network switch / device with an standard Rj45 port, could these data formats damage the switch / device.

Comment: The *"data format"* is irrelevant.  If the concern is physical damage, then the electrical signal is salient, specifically the voltages. RS-232 voltages could be more than 6 times the 1000BASE-T voltages (i.e. positive & negative 12 to 15 volts versus positive & negative 2 volts).

Answer (score 2):

HDBaseT is designed to coexist with/tolerate Ethernet, so neither damages the other. IEEE PoE for Ethernet is designed to not damage anything, so it's at least safe to plug to HDBaseT.

RS-232 adapters are a completely different thing. The high voltages and pinouts may well damage Ethernet ports (or vice versa) when connected.

RS-485 adapters shouldn't cause damage (it's differential with low voltage) but I wouldn't bet on it.